# RxSwift: Append elements to Observable<[_]>

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have an array (`Observable<[_]>`) that is a datasource for a tableview. I want to be able to append new elements to it and update the tableview every time new elements are appended to the array. I can't find how to add new elements to `Observable<[_]>`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a `Subject` such as `Variable`.  Then just treat the `value` property as your `Array` and `append` to it to add new elements.  Subscribe to the `Variable` via `asObservable()`.

I've simplified the code example by using `String`, however you'll want to use some kind of `UITableViewCell`.

```
let dataSource = Variable<[String]>([])

dataSource.value.append("some string A")

dataSource.asObservable()
    .subscribeNext { e in
        print(e)
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

dataSource.value.append("some string B")
```

Once you have your dataSource, you'll want to hook it up to a tableView via

```
dataSource.asObservable().bindTo(yourTableView.rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier("MyCellClass", cellType: MyCellClass.self)) { (row, element, cell) in
      // do your cell configuration here
}
```

Comment: Since Variable is planned for deprecation, any thoughts on how to do this with BehaviorRelay - the recommended alternative? behaviorRelay.value.append is not permitted since BehaviorRelay.value is a non-mutating member.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment in the issue, you can get the value of a `BehaviorRelay` by calling `value`. Then you can append to it and feed the new value back in by calling `accept`. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1501#issuecomment-349334148

Comment: That is what I ended up doing, but since the value is immutable, I am creating a new array rather than appending. There is a performance penalty for doing that. In my testing, the performance hit seems acceptable, so I'll keep it. But I'd love to have a way to do an actual append.